Iterator Optimization done by the rust compiler
I'm trying to understand how rust does optimization with iterators. Consider the following code
let v: Vec<T> = vec![...]
let v2: Vec<P> = v.into_iter().map(|x| x.transform()).collect();

where transform() consumes self and return another structure P. That is the function signature looks like this
impl T {
  fn transform(self) -> P {...}
}

If T and P have the same size, would the compiler be able to optimize the code to not allocate another vector in memory and do the map in place? While it is doing the map, it would have half of the vector being on type and another being another, but the structure of the code does not let the user access the vector in the broken state in between.
If this optimization is not done, is there a way to do it with unsafe code? I would iter_mut with transmute work? e.g.
    v.iter_mut().for_each(|x| {
        let p: *mut T = x;
        unsafe {
            let x = ptr::read(p);
            let y = x.transform();
            ptr::write(p, transmute::<P, T>(y));
        }
    });
    let v = unsafe {transmute::<Vec<T>, Vec<P>>(v)};

Lastly, if you could tell me the method you used to investigate the optimization that would be great. I'm new to low level programming so any pointer in the general direction would be greatly appreciated.

I don't think this is possible. Consider what happens if transform panics. Then stack would be unwinded and at some point vector would be dropped. This in turn would drop all of its elements. But some of them would be already P, and yet still would be called with T's drop implementation. Which would be an instant UB.

And as to your manual implementation, I don't know if transmuting Vec<T> into Vec<P> is sound. I think you should go through Vec::into_raw_parts, casting pointer, and then through Vec::from_raw_parts.

Also note, that T and P having the same size is not enough and they have to have the same alignment as well for this transmute, to have sense.

Ah ok I had overlooked the alignment issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Yes, it would.
Okay, technically the compiler won't. But the standard library has specialization for that.
The docs even say that Vec might do that.

Vec may use any or none of the following strategies, depending on the supplied iterator:
...

perform the iteration in-place on the original allocation backing the iterator


In practice, currently it does.
Here's an example:
pub fn foo(data: Vec<u32>) -> Vec<i32> {
    data.into_iter().map(|v| v as i32).collect()
}

This compiles to the following assembly:
example::foo::h155d07d1e93916ee:
        mov     rax, rdi
        movabs  rcx, 4611686018427387903
        and     rcx, qword ptr [rsi + 16]
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rsi]
        movups  xmmword ptr [rdi], xmm0
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 16], rcx
        ret

That is, only move the vector. Not even a loop.
In-place iteration only works if:

The alignment of the source and destination type is the same.
The iterator adapters used are from std (since only they implement the required traits).
The original collection supports in-place iteration (only Vec and BinaryHeap).
If you have flatten(), flat_map() or array_chunks() in the pipeline, there is some complicated calculation going on.

The implementation is here.
If you need a guarantee, don't transmute the Vec, it is unsound. Instead, use Vec::from_raw_parts().

Thanks for the excellent answer. Can I ask why transmuting the Vec is unsound?

@DE0CH Because the layout of Vec isn't guaranteed.
